# Make single user problem

Tags: objects

I have a problem when I try to make a single user of two linked objects. I have been successful at this in the past but for some or other reason I am not successful now. First I select the two linked objects, then I select in object mode Object>Relations>Make Single User>Object & Data & Materials. Absolutely nothing happens after this. When I left-click one object, both objects are still selected. I have tried Blender 2.7, 2.8, 2.91.2, 2.92.0 but without any success. I include a screenshot.
Can someone maybe hint me in the right direction. Your help is much appreciated!

[image: To illustrate my point!]

Comment: Hello :) Your outliner shows only one object. Perhaps those are two *meshes* inside one object? You can separate them through *Mesh > Separate > Loose parts*

Comment: Hi Jachym! Thank you for your response. I followed your procedure and the green felt underneath most chess pieces to prevent scratching was seperated from the rest of the piece. In object mode again when I left- click on the green felt,it shows up in both rook-objects and when I left-click the top of the rook, it shows up in both linked rooks.I would like to include a screenshot but it seems that I can't.Not the answer what I am looking for but definitely something that I learned from you and will remember for the future!Thank you! The question remains open-common, someone must know something!

Comment: Hey :). Well, you can share the file (https://pasteall.org/blend/), otherwise it's just guessing.

Comment: I would like to share my file 'ProblemProject.blend' at the following URL: https://pasteall.org/blend/46bfdd90bed244458522097e21a8124b .See if someone can make out heads or tails of it! I use Blender 2.91.2 .

Comment: Hello :). There's an *Array modifier* that makes things a bit confusing. Either apply it or remove it. Other than that - it's just *Mesh > Separate by loose parts* again and again. you can then join parts back using *Object > Join*.

Comment: Hi Jachym! Thank you for your help and patience! Problem solved! The linked rook-duplicate disappeared when I removed the modifier. Thank you so much! Have an awesome day!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project :)